# zsh: command not found: get-graphql-schema

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, graphql-schema, ferry

I'm trying to download my graphcms schema into my flutter project. I'm using Ferry as the graphql client.

According to the [ferry docs](https://ferrygraphql.com/docs/codegen#:%7E:text=get%20generated%20correctly.-,Download%20Your%20GraphQL%20Schema,-%23) I just need to run `npm install -g get-graphql-schema` and then run `get-graphql-schema [ENDPOINT_URL] > lib/schema.graphql` to download the schema.

However, when I try running that command, I get this in the terminal: `zsh: command not found: get-graphql-schema` .

I'm using an m1 mac - not sure if this is an m1-specific issue.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the apollo-cli by command:

```
brew uninstall apollo-cli
```

And try run `get-graphql-schema [ENDPOINT_URL] > lib/schema.graphql` again.
In my case, it's successfully.